# Литературная речь

Tags: грамотная-речь

Однажды меня озадачило, когда в книге, вышедшей в московском издательстве "Альфа-книга", встретилось слово "консерва". Я чего-то не понимаю и это уже стало литературным словом, или же теперь в издательствах такие редакторы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аааа... Нет, слово не литературное. Но очень популярное в близких к Одессе кругах.
Книга не художественная была часом?

Comment: Художественная. Фэнтези какое-то. Просто, честно говоря, меня это убило. Если ТАКОЕ издают и пропускают редакторы... Думаю, или это я чего-то не понимаю, или хана русскому языку)))
Причем, если бы это было сюжетно оправдано, это одно, но это проскочило в тексте от автора!

Answer (score 0):

От автора или от  героя произведения?

Comment: От автора или от героя произведения?